# Google Sheets Query Image to show up from Query result

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I can't figure out how to get an image to display in cells in my gsheet when they are coming out of a query. I've tried various forms of arrayformula and query combos but nothing. Would love any help.

**Tried this, with A4:A21 being the image URLs**
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({B4:B21, image(A4:A21)},
"select Col1, Col2 LABEL Col1 'ID', Col2 'Image Showing'", 1))

Also tried this, with A4:A21 being the image URLs**

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({B4:B21, "=image(""" & A4:A21 & """)"},
```

"select Col1, Col2 LABEL Col1 'ID', Col2 'Image Showing'", 1))

Any help is greatly appreciated.

[Sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DpKyQsm88VLT3UugalmSGUsxEuvEMnAtgxGXPLwS170/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Query doesn't recognize Image type. See [this](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/74035/importrange-query-wont-import-image), which points to the `QUERY()` [manual](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en).

> Each column of data can only hold boolean, numeric (including date/time types) or string values.

Instead, you can do what you're trying with `HLOOKUP()`s:

```
=ArrayFormula({HLOOKUP("ID",B4:B21,ROW(B4:B21)-3),IMAGE(HLOOKUP("Image URL",A4:A21,ROW(A4:A21)-3))})
```

or

```
=ArrayFormula(
{
    HLOOKUP("ID",B4:B21,ROW(B4:B21)-3),
    IMAGE(HLOOKUP("Image URL",A4:A21,ROW(A4:A21)-3))
})
```

Looks up each url and applies `IMAGE` to it after.

Edit:  Accounting for the Display Status Column:

```
=ArrayFormula(
{
    HLOOKUP("ID",B4:B21,ROW(B4:B21)-3),
    IF(C4:C21="Yes",IMAGE(HLOOKUP("Image URL",A4:A21,ROW(A4:A21)-3)),)
})
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a clever solution. I should have mentioned (and I re-added to my sample sheet) that this is part of a larger set of data where I'm using Query to check various things. So for example I have a "display status" column and only want to show if it's YES.

`=ARRAYFORMULA({QUERY({B5:B21}, "SELECT Col1"),IMAGE(QUERY({A5:A21}, "SELECT Col1"))})`  this seems to work sort of, but gives me no real query type ability for display status

Comment: @tlhmode Got it, easy fix.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using `ARRAYFORMULA` and `IMAGE(QUERY())` and it accounts for multiple columns!

[Google Sheets Example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DaoUVfXahdmic1e8QJeSAPp80_nRmRoPz27JUz8n118/edit?usp=sharing)

```js
=ARRAYFORMULA({

  ({
    QUERY(
      {data!A1:C}, "SELECT Col1 WHERE Col1 is not null ORDER BY Col1 asc"
    )
  }),

  ({
    "IMG";
    IMAGE(
      QUERY(
        {data!A2:C}, "SELECT Col3 WHERE Col3 is not null ORDER BY Col1 asc"
      ),2
    )
  }),

  ({
    QUERY(
      {data!A1:C}, "SELECT Col2 WHERE Col1 is not null ORDER BY Col1 asc"
    )
  })

})
```

[image]