# Google Sheets: Adding images to queried cells

Tags: image, google-sheets, filter, match, google-query-language

So what I'm trying to do is add images that show up next to certain cells while maintaining the ability to have a drop down that will sort through various columns. I want to add visuals because the community this is for speaks many different languages, and I want it to be an accessible sheet.

I've made an example of what I'm trying to do [on this sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZcMTArzUjfZCtTMt4jZaRbLevZZaCTF6V5xjXZsAzw0/edit#gid=1776404983) with some placeholder images on the "Data" sheet. These images aren't carried over to the "Sorted Data" sheet. I know the query function on its own can't be used to bring images in from another sheet, so I want to know how I could get this kind of setup while maintaining images. This sheet is editable.

While looking for answers, I found this: [Google Sheets Query Image to show up from Query result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63961066/google-sheets-query-image-to-show-up-from-query-result)

It's the closest I've seen. I'm struggling, however, on how I might translate this to what I'm trying to do here in terms of sorting the data. I've also seen people say some functions don't work with a lot of images, only loading a few. I'm not sure how true that might be, but just in case it's relevant, there likely will be a lot of images on this sheet.

I'm completely open to anything I may have missed, any changes I could make, any other functions, and script if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

query is not suitable for this job. use:

```
=SORT(FILTER(Data!B3:W500, Data!C3:C500<>""))
```

[image]

---

```
=SORT(FILTER(Data!B3:W500, Data!C3:C500<>""), MATCH(Z3, B2:2, 0), IF(AA3="ASC", 1, 0))
```

[image]